# How to search in angularjs using a dropdown

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

Please tell me how to add a dropdown search filter.
I have two dropdowns: one is a folder list and the second is a category list.

This is my code

```
<!--folder start-->

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="iPkFolderId" data-ng-model="iPkFolderId" ng-change="getchange(iPkFolderId)" id="iPkFolderId" required
                data-ng-options="option.iPkFolderId as option.vFolderName for option in getFolder">
            <option value="">Select Folder</option>
        </select>
        <span data-ng-show="submitted && sliderform.iPkFolderId.$invalid">
            <span class="text-danger" data-ng-show="sliderform.iPkFolderId.$error.required">Select Folder</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!--folder end-->

<!--category start-->

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="iDocumentCategoryId" data-ng-model="iDocumentCategoryId" id="iDocumentCategoryId" required
                data-ng-options="option.iPkDocCatId as option.vDocCat for option in getDocumentCategory">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
        </select>
        <span data-ng-show="submitted && sliderform.iDocumentCategoryId.$invalid">
            <span class="text-danger" data-ng-show="sliderform.iDocumentCategoryId.$error.required">Select Document</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!--category end-->
```

This is how I used filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection | filter:iPkFolderId">
```

I want the data which has the same value as the selected drop down option - how do I add a search filter?

Comment: Show some code? what you have been tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-value for your options and provide a value not just an empty string

```
<option ng-value="someValue of an ng-repeat item">Select Category</option>
```

Comment: that's not problem, i just pass id as value and have to find name in table

Comment: have a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions